# Loop variable as nth-of-type selector

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm trying to access a particular nth-of-type element based on loop variable i.

```
 for(var i=0;i< data.length; i++){
            $(".sm1:nth-of-type(i)").css("background-color","red");
        }
```

am i doing it right ? if wrong can i know the method to do so ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(".sm1:nth-of-type("+ i + ")")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not doing it right.
You are giving the string `".sm1:nth-of-type(i)"` as is. Therefore, jQuery takes the `i` as a character, not as a variable. You need to explicitly use the variable in there. Combine strings and variables using the `+`-sign.

Try this: `$(".sm1:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").css("background-color","red");`

Comment: Oh ! I get it now . Thanks :)

Comment: I ran into a small problem, in the Loop ,i starts from 0 , but nth-of-type starts numbering from 1 right ?

Comment: That is correct. Just write (i+1) and it will fix your problem. You can also start the loop at 1.

Comment: yes done . I assigned i+1 to a variable and used that variable though . Since ,i+1 will work i  Will change it .

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i< data.length; i++){
            $(".sm1:nth-of-type({i})").css("background-color","red");
        }
```

or

```
for(var i=0;i< data.length; i++){
            $(".sm1:nth-of-type("+i+")").css("background-color","red");
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you , will try both of them